# Copy Value from One key to another in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, data-migration

I am trying to migrate data in mongodb from **old schema** to **new schema** in mongodb. where slug_url is added which is exact copy of value of key 'name'. how can i acheive this using mongoshell ?

Previous Data :

```
{
name:'test',
}
```

Want

```
{
name:'test',
slug_url:'test'
}
```

Comment: This is a long standing question with long standing answers. [The MongoDB 4.2 solution](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/#update-with-an-aggregation-pipeline) ( if you have it ) would be `.updateMany({ }, [{ "$set": { "slug_url": "$name" } }])`. Older solutions are also documented on the existing answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done using forEach -

```
db.<collectionName>.find().forEach(function(result) 
{ 
db.<collectionName>.update({"_id" : result._id}, {$set : {"slug_url" : result.name}}); 
})
```

Comment: Just a side note, using for loop instead of the forEach will be much better here, since forEach doesn't await. Otherwise it's all good.